# Using an Android Intent to call a method, instead of a class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have seen questions similar to my issue on this forum but none that answer directly.

Essentially I have a broadcast receiver listening for an android action, the receiver is registered within one of my classes and, currently, calls a class. I would like for it to call a method within that class, without creating a second broadcast receiver (it seems pretty inefficient and poor coding practice to do so).

A lot of people have mentioned simply creating a broadcast receiver for that class but I don't want to use a broadcast receiver to call another broadcast receiver, any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share a snippet of code?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more....

Comment: Pls share code for understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you call the method from the same broadcast receiver, where you have registered that receiver.

Comment: Now that is something I had not thought of! You, sir, are a genius (or I am just very good at missing the obvious!). I will give it a go.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any way to call method from intent. You can call method from another class by making object of it on your class or if class is static.